# Some packets are flagged as INVALID by iptables

Tags: networking, iptables, apache-httpd, http-proxy, jboss

I configured a proxypass rule in order to redirect requests from the port 443 to a JBoss server running on port 8080.

All works fine except some 503 errors in the Apache log, around 10 per day:

In the error log:

> [error] (111)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (127.0.0.1) failed

In the access log, I've a corresponding 503 error. Nothing in my JBoss log.

For each error, coincide a packet flagged as invalid in the kernel log. I performed a tcpdump and for each invalid packet, it was a tcp SYN from the proxy to the JBoss server.

Why these packets are flagged as invalid ? Is that a serious problem ? Can I accept all invalid packets from 127.0.0.1 to dport 8080 ?

Comment: I would have to better understand the nature of these packets before I'd say with a blanket statement that you should just accept them. A SYN from JBoss in what context?

Comment: @slm What do you mean by "context" ? Our customers connect to our web application through apache on port 443. These requests are forwarded to JBoss on port 8080 (127.0.0.1:xxx -> 127.0.0.1:8080). Some of these requests, perhaps 3%, result in a 503 error due to invalid TCP SYN sent to JBoss. I've added a rule in iptables in order to accept invalid packets from 127.0.0.1 to port 8080. Nevertheless, the problem remains, we have a 503 error after few seconds :/

Comment: I performed a tcpdump and I'm now analyzing this dump with wireshark in order to understand why this packet is flagged as invalid. How can I find this information with wireshark ? Why the server doesn't send a SYN ACK ?

Comment: My point was that JBoss doesn't just randomly start sending out SYN packets, there is some underlying context (JBoss is replying to a client due to some previous connection). Without knowing that you aren't going to get very far with help here. I mean no disrespect in that previous statement BTW. I would try and figure out what JBoss is attempting to do via it's logs here if possible. A SYN pckt typically has no payload, so there isn't going to be more to gleam from wireshark outside of JBoss is trying to talk to me.

Comment: @slm Indeed, the connection is initiated by Apache and it sends a SYN packet to JBoss which is flagged invalid by iptables. First, Iptables was configured to REJECT this kind of packets, thus JBoss didn't reply with a SYN ACK. From this moment, I found "[error] (111)Connection refused". Now, I've added a rule in order to authorize invalid packet from lo to JBoss (8080). The error is no longer the same: "(110)Connection timed out". In the tcpdump I can see: SYN sent by Apache, SYN ACK sent by JBoss and then RST sent by Apache. The TCP retransmission occurs 5 times but with the same result.

Comment: @slm I guess the problem is not really the error seen in the log but the question is "why Apache is sending an invalid packet ?" Isn't it ? (sorry for my english, I'm a french native speaker)

Comment: @slm Thanks for your help. The problem is now solved and was related to iptables. I don't know why, some packets are flagged as INVALID when you use this kind of rules: `iptables -A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j REJECT` and `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset`. A message has been sent to the iptables mailinglist.

Comment: Glad you solved the issue. Write it up as an A to your own Q and then you can accept it. Should help others in the future that may get tripped up by it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is now solved and was related to iptables.

I don't know why, some packets are flagged as INVALID (1/1000) when you use this kind of rules:

`iptables -A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j REJECT`

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset`

As solution, I accept all packet (even invalid) from 127.0.0.1 from/to port 8080.

A message has been sent to the iptables mailinglist.

Comment: Side note: You may DROP invalid packets directly, non-syn REJECT, that's ok. Cheers

Comment: The updated iptables documentation tells you must never REJECT an INVALID packet, only DROP it. The explanation is in the manual (but didn't exist in 2014): https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#REJECT_(IPv4-specific)